# How to redimension an input if it's text is too large

Tags: php, html, css

I have to create some input type='submit' depending on different element inside an array. The problem is that if the text is too large I would like the input to increase it's height.

I edited this because what I really need is to put the text of the input in 2 lines instead of 1.

Here is some code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($mis_posts_sidebar);$i++)
{
    $name_sidebar = $mis_posts_sidebar[$i]->post_name;
    $title_sidebar = $mis_posts_sidebar[$i]->post_title;
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $name_sidebar;?>" style="border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(215, 214, 213, 0.50);">
    <input
    type="submit"
    name="<?php echo $name_sidebar;?>"
    value="<?php echo $title_sidebar;?>"
    id="<?php echo $name_sidebar;?>"
    style="font-size: 13.3pt; border: none; background-color: transparent; color: #00284b; font-weight: bold; width: 100%; text-align: left;">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want, so why you just don't count the text. If text is too long, do an <? echo height: xx px; ?> in style else <? echo height: auto ?>

Comment: Ok. Thats certainly a way to do it. I was wondering if there was some CSS that I could add to the style to do that.

Comment: Not that I know because css is actually a document language.

Comment: css overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 1):

Input will always be one line, otherwise you can use Textarea and style it as you need using CSS.